# qmake error when installing PyQt5

Tags: software-installation, python, path

I'm trying to install PyQt5 for python3 from source files.

I install SIP correctly.

Then when I want to prepare the make file for installing PyQt, I get this error:

```
#python3 configure.py

Error: /usr/bin/qmake failed to create a makefile. Make sure you have a working
Qt qmake on your PATH or use the -q argument to explicitly specify a working Qt
qmake.
```

Comment: What is your distribution, and why not use a binary package?

Comment: I'm using debian/xbuntu. Binary package will install pyqt just for default version of python which is 2.7 and I want it to be installed for python 3.

Comment: There's a `python3-pyqt5` package in Debian. You could backport it. Probably similar comments apply to Xubuntu.

Comment: Yes it is working with this package. But I still want to know how to resolve this error. Thanks.

Comment: Check the build dependencies for the `python3-pyqt5` and see if they are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you do not have `qmake` installed.  On Fedora this is in the Qt `-devel` package, but on debian / ubuntu it may be in it's own package; the two most likely candidates are:

```
> apt-cache search qmake
qt3-dev-tools - Qt3 development tools
qt4-qmake - Qt 4 qmake Makefile generator tool
```

You should be able to type `which qmake` and get a reply such as `/usr/bin/qmake`.